# Expired session cookie prevents successful login

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, session-timeout

For an ASP.NET web application using Forms Authentication I added the following code in `Global.asax` to log users out when their session expires:

```
void Session_Start(object s, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        /* cache clean up code */
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
    }
}
```

This is to prevent problems due to unchecked use of `Session` variables in pre-existing code. I noticed however that whenever the session expires while the user is not logged in the code prevents a successful log in, constantly redirecting the user to the log in page. The problem seems to lie with the session cookie that remains set and doesn't allow the session to renew, as deleting it re-enables normal log in. Editing the value of the session cookie also causes the log-in loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix for the above mentioned problem. Appending:

```
else
    Session.Add("dummy", 0);
```

solves the problem, although it does seem a bit unorthodox. It seems an empty session fails to renew the session id in the session cookie.